# Form within a form in Django?

Tags: django

I have been looking at the documentation and thought maybe inline-formsets would be the answer. But I am not entirely sure.

Usually whenever you create a ModelForm it is bound to the related Model only. But what if you wanted to edit two models within a form?

In a nutshell, when editing the class `conversation`, and selecting a `Deal` class from the dropdown, I would like to be able to change the status of the selected deal class as well (but not the deal_name). All within the same form.  Does Django allow that?

```
class Deal(models.Model):    
    deal_name           = models.CharField()
    status              = models.ForeignKey(DealStatus)

class Conversation(models.Model):
    subject             = models.CharField()
    deal                = models.ForeignKey(Deal, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Update**:

The reason I wasn't sure if inline-formssets are the answer is the following behaviour:

**View:**

```
call = get_object_or_404(contact.conversation_set.all(), pk=call_id)
ConversationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Deal, Conversation)
fset = ConversationFormSet(instance=call)    
variables = RequestContext(request, {'formset':fset})
return render_to_response('conversation.html', variables)
```

**Template**

```
{{ formset }}
```

The result I am getting is not what I expected. I am getting three forms of Conversation class, where the first one is filled out (due editing and passing in the isntance). However the `Deal` DropDown menu is not listed at all. Why?

Comment: This is exactly what inlines are for

Comment: @ArgsKwargs Thanks. I have updated the question, if you could have a look please.

Comment: Because of the way inlines work they expect the inlines always to be part of the Deal object you're editing, if you want to work the other way around you'll need another approach, you could hack in the deals field and create custom saving behaviour moving the conversation object to another deal if the deal field input does not correspond with the main object

Comment: Another option could have been loading that field with Ajax and send it back to the service. But I failed in my attempt. May you please be so kind and elaborate a bit more about your suggested approach above? Initially I wanted to allow any change to the status only within the conversation, to know which Conversation entry has caused the deal status to change. But if you think remodeling it could help, I am open to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and hope this will help someone else with the same problem in the future. I ended up redesigning my models.

I simply added the status also to my Conversation model.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    subject             = models.CharField()
    deal                = models.ForeignKey(Deal, blank=True, null=True)
    status              = models.ForeignKey(DealStatus)
```

In the view I added a custom save like this:

```
if form.is_valid():            
            call = form.save(commit=False)
            deal =  get_object_or_404(Deal.objects.all(), pk=call.deal.id)
            deal.status = call.status
            deal.save()
            call.save()
```

That works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use signal like this:

```
def update_deal_status(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        deal = Deal.objects.get(id__exact=instance.deal_id)
        deal.status  = instance.status 
        deal.save()

signals.post_save.connect(update_deal_status, sender=Conversation)
```